# Typo3, upgrade from 4.5 to 6.2, Symlinks are ignored

Tags: typo3

in Typo3 4.5.22 my symlinks from WebsiteURL with typo3_src to ../Typo3vers/typo3_src-4.7.20 are totally ignored by Typo3. I think my predecessor did some weird stuff. I copied everything to my local ubuntu 12.4 testserver and try to solve everything there.
Is there any possiblity to hardcode the typo3_src-link in any of the config-files?

Comment: Those links should be entirely transparent to TYPO3, so you shouldn't look in the TYPO3 code, but at the web server setup. Maybe the install tool (in 6.2) can you give you some hints what is wrong, though.

Comment: Hi Jost, thanks for your comment. Without the working Symlink I cannot switch to 6.2 easily. But nevertheless I solved the problem by installing another 4.5.22 on my Testserver without any stuff of my predecessor and this time the symlinks worked. So the difference had to be in the code as it's the same server.

Comment: In that case, try to compare both TYPO3 cores using a diff tool.